# Adding onclick to UI material button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add an onClick eventhandler into a material ui and sometimes it is called, sometimes it is not. However, it's working fine with regular buttons

```
 handleClick = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({ filtered: this.state.videos.filter(item => { 
            return item.category === value
        })
    })

<Button value="java" onClick={this.handleClick}  color="primary">Java</Button> 
<Button value="React" onClick={this.handleClick} color="primary">React</Button> 
<Button value="C#" onClick={this.handleClick}  color="primary">C#</Button> 
<Button value="javascript" onClick={this.handleClick} color="primary">JavaScript</Button>
```

when I updated to console.log to get event.target, I got the result shown in the image below
I found the issue, but still don't know how yo fix it. React adds two spans to the Button that have no attribute name, so when I click the button, the function gets called, but not when I click the span

[image]

Comment: Your code is ok. I did not find any issue. Can you please share your full code so that I can reproduce on my side.

Comment: @Khabir Can you check my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your handle click, you could also do:

```
return (item.category === value || item.category === event.target.innerHTML)
```

But obviously CD..’s answer is better

Answer (score 6):

You can use `event.currentTarget.value` instead of `event.target.value`.

Material-ui's `Button` has a nested `span` inside the `button`, so when you use `event.target.value` and the user clicks the `span` you get the `span` as `event.target`, if you'd use `event.currentTarget` you'd get the element that the event listener is attached to - the button.

See a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-cookies-s5moo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yo bro, next time you close questions, make sure to try the code before hand.

Comment: @Zocatelli, sorry, If you still need help lets chat at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Answer (score 0):

Besides relying on currentTarget, you can always curry the parameter to the callback function (imagine you are not passing in static content, but maybe the index of an iteration or some dynamic values stored in an object, etc)

Example

```
handleClick = (value) => () => {
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({ filtered: this.state.videos.filter(item => { 
            return item.category === value
        })
    })

<Button value="java" onClick={this.handleClick('java')}  color="primary">Java</Button> 
<Button value="React" onClick={this.handleClick('React')} color="primary">React</Button> 
<Button value="C#" onClick={this.handleClick('C#')}  color="primary">C#</Button> 
<Button value="javascript" onClick={this.handleClick('javascript')} color="primary">JavaScript</Button>
```